# How to parse polynomial for exponents

Tags: java, regex, split

If given a String such as `"(-2)x^(-2)+(3)x^(1)-(18)x^(-45)"` how would I use split() to get the exponents? So this example would return `[-2, 1, -45]`. I tried to figure out the regex notation but it's pretty confusing. The closest I've come is `string.split("x\\^\\(")` but it doesn't fully split it how I want to.

Comment: This isn't a good use case for `split`.  Set up a regex matcher and use `find` in a loop.

Comment: You wouldn't. You would write yourself a proper lexical analyzer. XY problem.

Comment: How would I set up a regex matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
String str = "(-2)x^(-2)+(3)x^(1)-(18)x^(-45)";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
List<String> exponents = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
    if(chars[i] == '^') {
        if(++i<chars.length && chars[i] == '(') {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while(++i<chars.length && chars[i] != ')') {
                sb.append(chars[i]);
            }
            exponents.add(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While valid (at a glance), this could be implemented less verbosely with a regex, as mentioned by @ajb

Comment: Agreed, there are always tradeoffs.  I generally prefer not to use regex as they are terrible to debug IMO but that's my preference.

Comment: Also, this is quite a bit faster than the regex version - if speed matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need a regex based solution:

```
    String line = "(-2)x^(-2)+(3)x^(1)-(18)x^(-45)";         
    String pattern = ".*?\\^\\(([\\d-]+)\\)[\\+-]*";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.MULTILINE);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {            
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));            
    }
```

[Sample Demo at Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hqH0g3vJd73BgD82)